# jquery $(window).on('load", function() not working as expected. Explanation?

Tags: jquery, event-handling, load

I have been trying to wrap my head around the .on event handler replacing the .live and .bind handlers and although I have used .on effectively in some cases it seems to just not work as expected, especially when it is bound to "load" from a dynamic source meaning if I try to run the below code snippets from an html file which itself was loaded dynamically via AJAX it fails silently.

As an example, I load test.html via ajax into a div and test.html has:

```
<script>
        $(window).on('load', 'body', function(){
            alert('test');
        });
</script>
```

That should in theory serve up an alert box when all of the elements on the page have loaded, correct? In practice it does nothing. The alert never fires. Same for this:

```
<script>
            $(document).on('load', 'body', function(){
                alert('test');
            });
</script>
```

In theory that should fire when the dom is fully loaded, in practice it does not fire at all.

This only occurs when these events are called from a dynamic location themselves but I would imagine that is the case quite often so is there a work around to make these events still fire when loaded dynamically or am I doing something wrong. I have run into this issue many and it is clearly an issue with the load event as if i were to change either of the two events to "click" instead of load and then clicked anywhere on the body, the alert would fire as expect. So my main question is what is up with the load event.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the .ready(), which is super useful (not gonna lie, I had a brain fart and forgot it as well)

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    alert('test');
  });
</script>
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: If the body isn't already in the DOM, you can't attach a handler to it. That's the point of delegation with `.on`.

Comment: Sorry I was thinking in terms of a predefined HTML doc. I changed it to the preferred and universal format

Comment: That works fine on a non dynamic page. But put that same code on a dynamically loaded page and it fail silently.